# DynamoDB concurrent write issue

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I'm having an issue when trying to implement optimistic lock for a write operation on an event triggered lambda.

I'm currently tring to implement the VersionAttribute field which increments on each update operation, the code is something like this:

```
const id = 1;

var retries = 0;
while (retries < 5){
  var item = getItem(id);
  item.config = newConfig();
  var params = {
    TableName: process.env.tableName,
    Key: { Id: id},
    ConditionExpression: '#versionAttribute = :versionAttribute',
    UpdateExpression: 'set #config = :config, #versionAttribute = :newVersionAttribute',
    ExpressionAttributeNames:
    {
      '#versionAttribute': 'VersionAttribute',
      '#config': 'Config'
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues:
    {
      ':versionAttribute': item.VersionAttribute,
      ':newVersionAttribute': item.VersionAttribute+1,
      ':config': config
    }
  };
  try{
    await dynamoDb.update(params).promise();
    break;
  }catch(err){
    retries++;
  }
}
```

The problem is that I'm still having some cases where the event is called at the same time and they are still overriding the previous update.

eg:
Event 1:

```
config = 
  a:true,
  b:false
}
Item:{
  Config: {
    a:false,
    b:false
  },
  versionAttribute:1
}
```

Event2:

```
config = {
  a:false,
  b:true
}
Item:{
  Config: {
    a:false,
    b:false
  },
  versionAttribute:1
}
```

Results:

```
Item:{
  Config: {
    a:false,
    b:true
  },
  versionAttribute:2
}
```

And instead of failing the second event and doing a retry, the item gets updated again and overrides the values of the Event 1.

Is there something that I'm doing wrong? Why is Dynamo not preventing the update for the second event if the conditions are not met?

Comment: I can't find anything wrong with your code so I wonder I think there's something wrong in the details in your question. The "Results" look exactly like Event2 succeeded but Event1 failed (maybe the two events raced and Event2 happened to win the race). Are you sure that Event1 did not fail? If you believe Event1 succeeded, do you have a printout of the results after Event1 succeeded?
Also don't forget that your code has a loop. Events would not actually "fail", they would just fail the first attempt and try again.

Comment: Hi @NadavHar'El thanks for your response! I added a logger on the try and catch sections to see if the .update was getting through or throwing an error but it's not entering into the catch section. The real code is actually combining the contents of the content operation so if it enters the retry loop you should actually see the results reflected on the final result. I just tried to simplify the explanation to try and see if I was doing something conceptually wrong.
I'm also logging the update input, so I know that both updates have the same versionAttribute, but non is throwing an error.

Comment: Just to add some info, I am logging the versionAttribute right before the dynamoDb.update, and they both have the same version, but none is throwing an error. That's why I'm wondering if Dynamo is locking the table for each update or if it may even generate a race condition on Dynamo itself.

The condition is being checked correctly, I tried changing the ExpressionAttributeValue to ':versionAttribute': item.VersionAttribute+1 and it does throw an error for all the calls.

Comment: I think it depends what is the type of your table, i.e. is it a global table, and if so I think the last writer wins.
 but as it seems both write requests are somehow going to 2 different partitions leading to the condition success and thus succeding

Comment: Also can you try using the Transact Write API once (i.e. implement pessimist locking) and check if that works?

Comment: Hi @satyaprakash, thanks for your response. I tried implementing documentClient.transactWrite but I had exactly the same results which makes it weirder.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it might be the problem but you are not awaiting the result of the dynamodb operation. I‘m not an expert but I‘m always using dynamodb sdk calls like `const result = await dynamodb.update(..).promise()` or a `then` or `catch` handler. It might be that you are not catching the error properly.

```
var documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

documentClient.update(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    else console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Hi Emilio, I forgot to put it on the example, but you are right, there must be an await on the operation. I just updated the code to reflect it. The error is actually being handled as I tried sending another value on the update for versionAttribute and it was throwing the conditional check error. Thanks for the reply!